# Finding Duplicate occurrences in column

Tags: sql, duplicates, return-value

I have 2 tables `Customer` and `meter`.

A `customer` might have multiple `meternbr` in `meter` table. `Customer` has a `customernbr` column.

I want to return customers who have more than one `meternbr` only. Look at the table below. I want to return only customers a and c with the `meternbr` also.

```
Customer  Meter
--------  -----
a          a-100
b          a-101
c          b-103 
d          c-104
           c-105
```

Comment: So you have 2 one column tables?  Still not too clear.

Comment: Show your tables schema and tag your question with the RDMS you are using

Answer (score 2):

If that is a single string (which i don't think is a good idea to begin with), and if your DBMS supports `LEFT/SUBSTRING and INSTR` you can do a `LEFT or a SUBSTRING`  combined with a `INSTR` that finds where is the first `'-'` index and get the customers that have more than one occurrence by using GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT(*) > 1.

```sql
SELECT LEFT(meterColumn,INSTR(meterColumn,'-')-1)
FROM meter
WHERE LEFT(meterColumn,INSTR(meterColumn,'-')-1) IN (
    SELECT LEFT(meterColumn,INSTR(meterColumn,'-')-1)
    FROM meter
    GROUP BY LEFT(meterColumn,INSTR(meterColumn,'-')-1)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
GROUP BY 1;
```

If those are two columns in the meter table (customerNbr) and (meterNbr), you could simply do:

```sql
SELECT customerNbr
FROM meter
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` Clause with `COUNT(*) > 1`.

Here's a working Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1b91/17

Pasting code and results below also:

**CREATE TABLES** (Note: Have not placed FK Constaint for demo purposes)

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
  customernbr NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE Meter
(
  meternbr NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  customernbr NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)
```

**INSERT DATA.** (Uncomment last 2 SELECT statements if you wanna see the data)

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES
('a'),
('b'),
('c'),
('d');

INSERT INTO Meter VALUES
('a-100','a'),
('a-101','a'),
('b-103','b'),
('c-104','c'),
('c-105','c'),
('d-106','d');

--SELECT * FROM Customer;

--SELECT * FROM Meter;
```

**RUN SELECT STATEMENT**

```
SELECT 
  customernbr AS 'Customer',
  meternbr AS 'Meter'
FROM Meter WHERE customernbr IN
(
  SELECT customernbr
  FROM Meter
  GROUP BY customernbr 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

**SEE RESULTS :)**

```
CUSTOMER    METER
a           a-100
a           a-101
c           c-104
c           c-105
```